# Are "open" and "empty" adverbs in "The food bins are broken open and empty."?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parsing

> The food bins are broken open and empty.

The words "open" and "empty" in the above mentioned sentence seem like adjectives, but in another sense they modify the verb "broken". So can we call them "adverbs"? Another sense of the sentence could be that "open" and "empty" describe the action as the bins are opened and emptied after breaking. So the function of the words *open and *empty is a little confusing.

Comment: They are adjectives since they describe a property of the "food bins" after they were broken, not the manner in which they were broken open.

Comment: So can we say, The song is sung beautiful and nice as to describe the noun song which appears little odd because we know the word beautiful is modifying the verb sung not song.

Comment: No: unlike "open, "beautiful" "and "nice" do not describe the resultant state of the song after it has been sung. Note that it should be "The song is sung beautiful**ly** and nice**ly**,

Comment: I think "open" isn't an independent adjective; *broken open* is an adjective, and *empty* is another.

Comment: Grammatically, it's no different to "The door is kicked open", where "kicked" is a verb and "open" is a predicative complement.

Comment: Still, *broken* groups with *open* in a way that it doesn't group with *empty*. You can say *broken open*, but not *broken empty*.

Answer (score 1):

> *The food bins are broken open and empty.*

"Empty" describes "the food bins" and thus is straightforwardly an adjective in predicative (PC) function.

"Open" is also an adjective, again in PC function. More specifically it is a resultative PC in that it ascribes the property of being "open" to "food bins" following the act of being "broken open".

"Open" is  not an adverbial since it doesn't describe the manner in which they are broken open (cf. *The food bins are broken hurriedly*).

Comment: I think "the food bins are open and empty" is fine, but don't like "broken open" as a predicate adjective phrase.  The addition of "broken" reduces the acceptability of the simpler structure.  I would reword it as "The food bins have been broken open and are empty"

Comment: @Vegawatcher I didn't say that "broken open" is a predicative AdjP. I said that "open" is predicative. "Broken" is of course a verb. The present tense in the original example is fine in an appropriate context.

Comment: It may be a difference in our dialects.  I personally would never say "something is broken open."